# Android DownloadManager non simultaneous downloads

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm looking for a way (except downloading one file each time) to download files with the 
Android `DownloadManager` each file at a time,
I've noticed the `DownloadManager` downloading files simultaneously, is there a way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can one download request at a time use `DownloadManager.enqueue(request)`

Comment: please, I mentioned this "(except downloading one file each time)"

Comment: In that case you may have to go for custom download service.